Major mode keybindings in Emacs 29
I am a long time evil-mode Spacemacs user, but now would like to roll my own config that copies my favourite parts of Spacemacs. I'm having some trouble with Keybindings for major modes.
I'm using Emacs 29. I've not needed general.el so far. Following this advice for using the newer Emacs 29 keybindings -
here. I've had success using keymap-set and which-key-add-keymap-based-replacements. Here's part of my config for the File keybindings I've configured, which works as expected:
(defvar-keymap my-files-keymap
  :doc "Key map for file functions"
  "f" #'find-file
  "s" #'save-buffer)

;;Add new key map to the leader
(keymap-set my-leader-map "f" my-files-keymap)

;;Add labels to the Files keymaps
(which-key-add-keymap-based-replacements my-files-keymap
  "f" "find"
  "s" "save")

;;Add Files to the Leader keymaps
(which-key-add-keymap-based-replacements my-leader-map
  "f" "Files")

But what I don't understand is the idiomatic way to add keybindings for major modes. For example, when in org mode I'd like SPC, m to show the major mode keybindings that I want for org mode, with which-key. But when in a different major mode, such as Clojure mode, I'd like SPC, m to show just the keybindings relevant to Clojure.
Is there any examples using defvar-keymap, keymap-set, and which-key-add-keymap-based-replacements for defining keys for different major modes, idiomatically?

It turns out this wasn't helpful, but I'll leave the answer in case it prevents anyone else writing an equivalent one.


when in org mode I'd like SPC, m to show the major mode keybindings that I want for org mode. But when in a different major mode, such as Clojure mode, I'd like SPC, m to show just the keybindings relevant to Clojure.

I think the nearest thing is:
(describe-keymap (current-local-map))

The local keymap isn't necessarily the major mode keymap; but in practice that will almost always be the case.
But typically you would simply use describe-mode -- C-hm by default -- which in most cases will show you that same information, and more besides.

I don't think that's what they are asking. I'm guessing they would want to override the default keymaps with evil-mode ones.

My answer certainly doesn't help much if you're not using the major mode's keymap to customize its keybindings.  It's not clear to me why anyone wouldn't use that keymap for that purpose -- but I don't use spacemacs, general, or evil, so there's plenty of scope for me to be missing things here...

If its an evil thing, though, I'm quite surprised if it doesn't already provide a help command for that specific purpose.  Surely every evil user has occasion to want to check the key bindings!

I'm looking for how to switch the key bindings when switching major modes using the new methods in Emacs 29. I'm using space as a leader key and it's which-key that displays the available keys and functions. This demo https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gojOZ3k1mmk is a great example of defining keys but does not cover switching them with the major mode. I don't think it matters I use evil mode. This works for non evil too.

I don't understand the question, sorry.  If you define your mode-specific key bindings in that mode's own keymap, then you don't need to "switch" anything -- those bindings will automatically be available in every buffer which is in that mode (and not in other buffers).  I don't believe there are any "new methods" in Emacs 29 which would suggest a different approach wrt major mode bindings -- AFAIK there are just some new and more-consistent ways of doing the same things we've always done (mostly a bunch of new keymap-* functions).

Is there any examples using defvar-keymap, keymap-set, and
which-key-add-keymap-based-replacements for defining keys for a couple of major modes that I can assign? In Spacemacs all major modes functions are called using SPC, m. If you are in org mode, you will see the functions for org mode and if you switch to a different major mode and press SPC,m, you'll get a different set keybindings to use.

Please edit your question instead of burying clarifications down here in comments to an answerr.

At this point my only suggestion is that you look at the spacemacs code to see how it's doing it.  If I understand correctly you want to mimic that behaviour, so copying and adapting its code for that feature seems like a sensible approach (or at least a starting point).

There are examples of defining key bindings for major modes pre Emacs 29. However, there are new functions for managing key maps in Emacs 29. I am looking for examples of how to use the new functions to define major modes.

Ok, add (to your question) a working example of what you want to do which uses the pre-29 functions, and someone will be able to show you how to do that same thing with the functions which were introduced in Emacs 29.


But what I don't understand is the idiomatic way to add keybindings for major modes.

The idiomatic way in Emacs 29+ is to use keymap-set as described in the manual. For example:
(keymap-set emacs-lisp-mode-map "C-c C-f" (lambda () (interactive) (message "Foo")))

Prior to that, the idiomatic and still a valid way was to use define-key:
(define-key emacs-lisp-mode-map (kbd "C-c f") (lambda () (interactive) (message "Bar")))

Explanation:
It is slightly wrong to think about adding keys to modes. We are not adding keybindings to modes, neither major nor minor, we are always adding keybindings to keymaps. Keymaps are associated with modes, by a simple mechanism, but we don't need to dive into that here.
Typically, we have to find out what is the name of a keymap used in a mode for which you would like to alter bindings. There is no difference for it being a minor or a major mode. The convention is to use mode-name-map, but there are both major and minor that do not obey this convention. Most of both major and minor modes do however.
Easy way to check if a mode follows this is to just type M-: mode-name- and than press TAB for completion. You can also check in which keymap is a known key bound by simply asking which function is bound to that key: C-h k and pressing your key. Emacs will answer with the "(found in  map)", amongst function name, and some other details. Unfortunately C-h b (describe-bindings) and C-h m (describe-mode), do not display names of keymaps. It would be handy if they did. Perhaps an idea for an easy to make patch for Emacs, for someone interested?
